# How to scrape data using selenium and python, I am trying to extract all the data which is in title div tag

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping

[**enter image description here**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PjTt3.png)

```
from selenium import webdriver
import pandas as pd
import time
import requests
from selenium.common.exceptions import ElementClickInterceptedException

driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="D:\\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
url = "https://www.fynd.com/brands/"
driver.get(url)
time.sleep(2)
driver.maximize_window()
luxury_brand_names = []
element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//div[@class='group-cards']")#.get_attribute("title")
#element = driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@classdata-v-2f624c7c data-v-73869697 title]")
for a in element:
    luxury_brand_names.append()
print(luxury_brand_names)
```

this is the code I am running and I am not getting any output, please help me with this, I am very new with coding and scraping data. I am trying to get all the data that is in the title div tag.

Comment: Why wouldn't you be fetching the divs of class "card-item" and then extracting the "title" attribute from them?

Comment: `element = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("//div[@class='group-cards']")#.get_attribute("title")` Here you are finding by `css_selector` but you have specified an `xpath`, so I am getting `selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: An invalid or illegal selector was specified`. What is the actual selector you're using?

Comment: first of all your `append()` is empty, nothing is added to the list, as second - element is a list of items, so you need to use like `luxury_brand_names.append(a.get_attribute("title")`

Comment: I am unsure what to use, hence I was trying different selector methods and trying to check if either of them works. I tried using C.Peck's answer but there are so many brands on that code and it gets revealed as you scroll down, this only captures a few of them.

Comment: Please can someone help me with the auto scrollable titles as well, there are so many titles in there and it increases as we scroll down.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is the answer using Beautiful Soup and selenium together -

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from selenium import webdriver


url = "https://www.fynd.com/brands/"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path ="D:\\chromedriver_win32\chromedriver.exe")
driver.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source,"html.parser")
title = soup.find_all('span',{'class':'ukt-title clrWhite'})
all_titles = list()
for jelly in range(len(title)):
    all_titles.append(title[jelly].text.strip())
    
print(all_titles)
```

Comment: Thank you! for the solution, please can you also help me with any link which can help me better understand scraping using beautiful soup?

Comment: Hi! I'm glad that my solution could solve your problem. Beautiful Soup is a wonderful library to scrape static websites. You can check out it's documentation for guidance. For the time being you can check [this](https://realpython.com/beautiful-soup-web-scraper-python/) out.

Answer (score 1):

I think the only things you need are to change your selector, identify with `find_elements`, and loop through the elements. Also you need to actually pass a value in to `append()`. It should be

```
elements = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("div.card-item")
for element in elements:
    luxury_brand_names.append(element.get_attribute('title'))
```

Comment: Thank you! Please can you help me with one more thing in this? When you look in the image there are so many brands and it keeps on increasing when you scroll down the page, how can I handle that and make sure it is also in my list?

Comment: Can you ask a new question for this new issue?

Comment: Sure! Will ask that as a new queestion

Answer (score 0):

first of all your `append()` is empty, nothing is added to the list

as second - need to change
`element = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("//div[@class='card-item']")`
to be as a list of items, so you can use it in your loop like:

`luxury_brand_names.append(a.get_attribute("title")`

Comment: `element` is not a list of items the way it is currently defined, `find_element_by_css_selector()` will return just one element (well it would if the selector was correct)

Comment: right, the selector also should be changed